# How fast is loading from a jar as opposed to loading from outside the jar? Is it ok to load a file within the jar in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

My understanding is that a major point of contention with reading a file during a unit test is that it is slow. There may be 1000 unit tests and we want the build to complete quickly so the unit tests must be fast. Disk I/O is known to be slow, therefore a good practice is to avoid unit tests that read from a file. Is it faster to read files from within the JAR rather than from outside the JAR? If so, in some cases it might be ok to read from a file within the JAR.

Comment: Why not write some test cases and time it yourself?  That would give you better information suited to your particular needs and environment.

Comment: Agreed.  Write some test cases and time them yourself, in your own environment.

Comment: `Disk I/O is known to be slow` disk from what century? I would not consider SSD disks to be slow :-).

Comment: You’ve fallen into the fallacy that is called Premature Optimization. Unless your Unit Tests are already very slow there is no need to spend any time worrying about Disk I/O. It’s highly unlikely Disk IOPS are going to bottle next your Unit Tests. If they do they aren’t Unit Tests.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on **what** you have to read from files.

You can replace reading from file with **static final constants** in classes and just read the constants from there. This would highly increase the time. But if the information that must be read is too large, this cannot be applied.

I would say that it doesn't matter if you read the files from the jar or from outside, or the difference is negligible.